# keeping variable results after turtle dies netlogo

Tags: netlogo, storing-data

Looking for a way to store a turtle length of stay in the model after they have left the model. My model runs for several months and a few thousand turtles enter, undergo process then leave the area. It's complicate model (it's a hybrid DES and ABM) so I've tried to reproduce the simple bit below.

Turtles will be created at every tick and given a random length of stay but will only be able to begin process when they move to the right area (area-name) and when their time is up they leave the area. Their time-in-system reflects the wait for the area and the length-of-stay which I want to save once they're complete. If I leave them in the model it starts to break down after a couple of months and I suspect this is because the model has too many turtles still in the system for calculation and is inefficient.

```
go

create turtles 2
 [
  set time-in-system 0
  set length-of-stay ceiling ((random-normal 48 4) + ticks)]
  set shape "person"
  if any? area-name with [not any? turtles-here]
   [move-to one-of area-name]
 ]

undergo-process

end


to-undergo-process

ask turtles with [shape = "person"]
[
set time-in-system time-in-system + 1
]

ask turtles-on area-name
[if ticks = length-of-stay
 [set shape "dot"
  move-to exit-door]

end
```

I can then plot and see in realtime to make sure it is working

```
 histogram time-in-system of turtles with [shape = "dot"]
```

but can't seem to figure out how to store them as unique values for plotting after the model has run and I have a dataset of outcomes without keeping them alive in the model. The real-time plot isn't necessary as long as I can store the unique values after they have left

If I ask them to die then I lose the unique values in the histogram. I don't want a tally of all values but each turtle's unique value at the end of the process after they left - at the moment the only solution I have to storing them is as an agent-set that stays alive in the exit-door patch but this takes up a lot of calculation power as the model progresses for months...

There may be a really simple command for this but I've been going round in circles through the programming manual trying to find it. Any tips appreciated

Comment: just as a side note, if you are planning to run your model for actual, real-time months, I highly recommend that you use `export-world` to save your progress regularly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a list storing the values of turtles that left.

Isolating only the code that is relevant for this purpose, it would be something like:

```
globals [
 times
]

to setup
 set times (list)
end

to leave-simulation   ; This being executed by turtles.
 set times lput (time-in-system times)
 die
end
```

Comment: Many thanks Matteo. It seemed like there would something that simple but it never occurred to me lists could be storage for values outside the actual processes. Will give it a go

Answer (score 1):

If your program is going to run for actual months, I recommend you use the `file-write` command to store your data. This way the data is preserved if the program halts for any reason; it gives you much more freedom to do the analysis you want without running the full simulation again.
If you write to a .csv (comma separated value) file, you can use almost any program (excel, R, matlab, python, C# or back to netlogo) to plot a histogram.

Comment: excellent suggestion especially for the times it crashes and I lose everything. Will check this out too